# What really happens when call setCancelsTouchesInView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

Wondering what really happens when i call setCancelsTouchesInView. It is not covered in the official document http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

ACB quoted the `UIGestureRecognizer` reference.  To make it a little more concrete, suppose you have a view with a pan gesture recognizer attached, and you have these methods in your view controller:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan");
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"touchesMoved");
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"touchesEnded");
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"touchesCancelled");
}

- (IBAction)panGestureRecognizerDidUpdate:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"panGesture");
}
```

And of course the pan gesture recognizer is configured to send the `panGestureRecognizerDidUpdate:` message.

Now suppose you touch the view, move your finger enough for the pan gesture to be recognized, and then lift your finger.  What does the app print?

**If the gesture recognizer has `cancelsTouchesInView` set to `YES`,** the app will log these messages:

```
touchesBegan
touchesMoved
touchesCancelled
panGesture
panGesture
(etc.)
```

You might get more than one `touchesMoved` before the cancel.

So, if you set `cancelsTouchesInView` to `YES` (the default), the system will cancel the touch before it sends the first message from the gesture recognizer, and you won't get any more touch-related messages for that touch.

**If the gesture recognizer has `cancelsTouchesInView` set to `NO`,** the app will log these messages:

```
touchesBegan
touchesMoved
panGesture
touchesMoved
panGesture
touchesMoved
panGesture
(etc.)
panGesture
touchesEnded
```

So, if you set `cancelsTouchesInView` to `NO`, the system will continue sending touch-related messages for the gesture touch, interleaved with the gesture recognizer's messages.  The touch will end normally instead of being cancelled (unless the system cancels the touch for some other reason, like the home button being pressed during the touch).

Comment: Thanks! When you set cancelsTouchesInView to No, the event will be cancel popping right?

Comment: I don't understand what “cancel popping” means.

Comment: This is an old thread so Apple might have changed the behavior by now, but in case of `cancelTouchesInView` set to `true` I get a different order of calls: `touchesBegan`, `tochesMoved`, `panGesture (sender.state .began)`, `touchesCancelled`, `panGesture (sender.state .changed)`, `panGesture (sender.state .changed)`, ... . So basically the difference is that `touchesCancelled` is called after the first call of `panGesture`, which at least in my case and according to my logic is not what I would expect and want. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Sounds like they changed it in the 9 years since I investigated.

Answer (score 2):

From the apple developer portal [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **cancelsTouchesInView** — If a gesture recognizer recognizes its gesture,
>   it unbinds the remaining touches of that gesture from their view (so
>   the window won’t deliver them). The window cancels the previously
>   delivered touches with a (touchesCancelled:withEvent:) message. If a
>   gesture recognizer doesn’t recognize its gesture, the view receives
>   all touches in the multi-touch sequence.
>
> **cancelsTouchesInView:**
>
> A Boolean value affecting whether touches are
>   delivered to a view when a gesture is recognized.
>
> *@property(nonatomic) BOOL cancelsTouchesInView*
>
> **Discussion**
>
> When this
>   property is YES (the default) and the receiver recognizes its gesture,
>   the touches of that gesture that are pending are not delivered to the
>   view and previously delivered touches are cancelled through a
>   touchesCancelled:withEvent: message sent to the view. If a gesture
>   recognizer doesn’t recognize its gesture or if the value of this
>   property is NO, the view receives all touches in the multi-touch
>   sequence.

Comment: Whats is ment by "the touchs of that gesture that are PENDING.."?