# Why does location not appear in touchesEnded?

Tags: location, swift2, uigesturerecognizer, touchesbegan, touchesended

I'm looking for the final position of `touchesEnded`.  My `touchesBegan` code looks like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   if let touch = touches.first {
       touchStart = touch.locationInNode(self)
       print("touchStart_1: \(touchStart)")
   }
}
```

The print gives me the location.

In `touchesEnded`, I have the following:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
  if let touch = touches.first, start = touchStart {
    print("touchStart_2: \(touchStart)")
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    print("touchEnded: \(location)")
  }
}
```

Neither of these prints returns anything.  As additional information, I'm using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` as well elsewhere but I understand that gesture recognisers work independently of touches.  Any idea what's up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this 2 gesture properties :

```
let swipeGesturte: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipeAction:")
swipeGesturte.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
swipeGesturte.cancelsTouchesInView = false // 1.
swipeGesturte.delaysTouchesEnded = false // 2.
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesturte)
```

For More about **cancelsTouchesInView** :[What really happens when call setCancelsTouchesInView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042632/what-really-happens-when-call-setcancelstouchesinview)