# How to dismiss UISearchBar keyboard without effecting other functionalities?

Tags: ios, swift

[image: This]   is how my screen looks like..

Now my code for dismissing the keyboard when the use of searchbar is over:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

        @objc func handleTap() {
        searchbar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

By this my keyboard is getting dismissed but whenever using this, the tableview DidSelectRowAt is no more working (Though there is no error or warning). I am confused that what is the problem exactly. Please help! Thanks is advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `cancelsTouchesInView` to false, for detailed explanation: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13042756/6576315)

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboard() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    
    @objc
    func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Usage:

call `hideKeyboard()` in the viewDidLoad of the controller.